# Running a Selenium2 IDE test case on the command line

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I need to use the Selenium IDE to create tests for projects we are working on, but to then take these tests and run them from the command line.

The situation is that we want our developers to be able to use the IDE to test websites using a central repository of test suites using the Selenium IDE. We also need the same tests (i.e. in the IDE HTML format) to be run by a CI server (Jenkins) on Sauce Labs.

I have found that the export from the IDE isn't great (test cases that worked on the IDE don't work from the command line). I also need to use WebDriver, e.g Selenium2.

This must be possible but I just cannot see how to do it.

Comment: If anyone comes across this, there is also: https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java which is really good.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Selunit](http://www.selunit.org) it combines Selenium tests in Selenese HTML format with Continuous Integration. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.selunit.org/2011/05/23/comprehensive-selenium-integration-in-hudson/) how to execute Selenium tests directly from Selenium IDE in Hudson builds and to benefit from its reporting capabilities provided for JUnit, where Selunit transforms Selenium reports to.

Comment: Nice answer, and it is leading me in the right direction, but I need to utilise Sauce Labs.  I will take a look a more detailed look at Selunit.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides a command-line test script runner, but it's well hidden.  Check out the `-htmlsuite` [option](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#run-selenese-directly-within-the-server-using-htmlsuite) of `selenium-server.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

In windows system you have to download `selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar` and Browser(IE, chrome) driverserver after downlaod you have to open CMD and run command

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer32.exe